# How can I solve the following error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"?

Tags: reactjs

How can I solve that error in the following code:

```
function App() {
  
  const [cityName, setCity] = useState("");

  const [weather, setWeather] = useState("");

  const getWeather = () => {
    fetch('https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=1ac5f1f1e4da4c39832151041211205&q=' + {cityName} + '&aqi=no')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setWeather("City: " + data.location.name 
        + " Local time: " + data.location.localtime 
        + " Last update: " + data.current.last_updated 
        + " Temperature in °C: " + data.current.temp_c 
        + " Temperature in °F: " + data.current.temp_f 
        + " Condition: " + data.current.condition.text 
        + " Wind speed in mph: " + data.current.wind_mph 
        + " Wind speed in kph: " + data.current.wind_kph 
        + " Wind degree: " + data.current.wind_degree
        + " Pressure mb: " + data.current.pressure_mb 
        + " Pressure in: " + data.current.pressure_in 
        + " Precipitations mm: " + data.current.precip_mm 
        + " Precipitations in: " + data.current.precip_in 
        + " Humidity: " + data.current.humidity 
        + " Cloud: " + data.current.cloud 
        + " Feelslike °C: " + data.current.feelslike_c 
        + " Feelslike °F: " + data.current.feelslike_f
        );
      });
  };
  
  return (
    <center>
      <p><font color="bluesky" size="10">Weather</font></p>
      <div class="card-body">
        <input type="text" id="city" onChenge={event => setCity(event.target.value)} placeholder="Type the name of city"></input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-secondary" onClick={getWeather}>Check weather</button>
        <h3>{weather}</h3>
      </div>
    </center>
  );
}
```

Example result for Chicago:

```
{
   "location":{
      "name":"Chicago",
      "region":"Illinois",
      "country":"United States of America",
      "lat":41.85,
      "lon":-87.65,
      "tz_id":"America/Chicago",
      "localtime_epoch":1621352167,
      "localtime":"2021-05-18 10:36"
   },
   "current":{
      "last_updated_epoch":1621351800,
      "last_updated":"2021-05-18 10:30",
      "temp_c":20.0,
      "temp_f":68.0,
      "is_day":1,
      "condition":{
         "text":"Overcast",
         "icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/122.png",
         "code":1009
      },
      "wind_mph":8.1,
      "wind_kph":13.0,
      "wind_degree":140,
      "wind_dir":"SE",
      "pressure_mb":1023.0,
      "pressure_in":30.7,
      "precip_mm":0.0,
      "precip_in":0.0,
      "humidity":63,
      "cloud":100,
      "feelslike_c":20.0,
      "feelslike_f":68.0,
      "vis_km":16.0,
      "vis_miles":9.0,
      "uv":3.0,
      "gust_mph":17.9,
      "gust_kph":28.8
   }
}
```

Comment: First of all, use a code block. Enclose your code with "````". How did people suppose to read what you have posted like that?

Comment: onChenge? It's supposed to be onChange. And please use code formatting

Comment: And add a console.log to your fetch callback to check the data structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax is wrong in this line:

```
'https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/c...ey=1ac5f1f1e4da4&q=' + {cityName} + '&aqi=no'
```

`{ cityName }` creates an object using the shorthand property name syntax. It is equivalent to `{ "cityName": cityName }`. When you append an object to a string, it creates `"[object Object]"`

```js
const cityName = "Chicago",
      URL = 'https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=123&q=' + {cityName} + '&aqi=no'
      
console.log(URL)
```

You need to use backticks (`` ` ``) instead of `'` and use `${}` for the variable substitution.

```
`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=123&q=${cityName}&aqi=no`
```

Snippet with your code:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [cityName, setCity] = useState("");
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState("");

  const getWeather = () => {
    fetch(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=1ac5f1f1e4da4c39832151041211205&q=${cityName}&aqi=no`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setWeather(`City: ${data.location.name} 
        Local time: ${data.location.localtime}
        Temperature in °C: ${data.current.temp_c}`
        );
      });
  };
  
  return (
    <center>
      <p><font color="bluesky" size="10">Weather</font></p>
      <div class="card-body">
        <input type="text" id="city" onChange={event => setCity(event.target.value)} placeholder="Type the name of city"></input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-secondary" onClick={getWeather}>Check weather</button>
        <h3>{weather}</h3>
      </div>
    </center>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
```

Comment: I know that line is the problem, but I don't know other way to put the city name in API call. I tried your suggestion, but I get the same error.Can you give me another hint ? Please.

Comment: @Elisei_01 you have typo in `city` input. It should be `onChange` instead of `onChenge`. I have added a runnable react snippet with your code. It works fine after that

Comment: It works.... thank you a lot :) I really appreciate it. :D

Answer (score 0):

First of, I suggest not posting your API key publicly, unless you're fine with other people using it.

Second, I can only assume that when you call this API and it doesn't find a location, it returns an `error` property or something like that.

So there are two ways you can solve it:

1. Use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), i.e. write something like `"City: " + data.location?.name //etc. etc.`
2. Before you perform the `setCity` operation, check if `data` has the properties you need or doesn't have an `error` property or something

Answer (score 0):

The error means `data.location` is `undefined`. You should check the data fetched by the API.

If you know `data.location` MIGHT not be defined, use optional chaining instead.
i.e.

```js
data.location?.name
```

This will return `undefined` instead of returning the error you got if `data.location` is `undefined`.

BTW, you may want to take a look at the way you set the `weather` state as well. Unless you absolutely need the data that way, it is not a good practice overall.
Have you considered the following instead?

```
setWeather({
  city: data.location.name ,
  localTime: data.location.localtime,
  lastUpdated: data.current.last_updated 
  // ... 
})
```